# Django freeze when use Form

Tags: python, django, forms

Django freeze when I try to render a form.

This is my forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Evento

class EventoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Evento
        fields = ['codreserva','fecha','incidencia','descripcion']
```

And this is my model:

```
class Evento(models.Model):
   codreserva = models.ForeignKey(Reserva, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Cod. Reserva')
   fecha = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha')
   incidencia = models.ForeignKey(Incidencia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Incidencia', null=True, blank=True)
   descripcion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
   usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   activo = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Activo')
   fechacierre = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha cierre', null=True, blank=True)
```

Just doing this:

```
e = EventoForm()
e.as_table()
```

Django freeze for minutes, and stop webbrowser

Debugging, I can see it stop in boundfields.py.

My Django version is 2.2.12 an Python 3.8 and I try with diferent browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The relational model of foreingkey "codreserva" has more than a one million of records.
When I try to show the form It wait to render all de  of the selector.